# Unit Testing Groovy Class Spring and Visibility

Tags: spring, groovy

I am attempting to test a Groovy class in Spring. I basically have a Java interface. And wrote a Groovy class to implement that interface.

I put the Groovy class in the same package. When I go to write a unit test every Java class is visible, but the Groovy class is not visible. I want to write a unit test on the groovy class? Maybe I am just dense, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same requirements and followed the directions here (http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) to get an instance of the groovy class to work with and test.  Specifically, the solution I used was located under the "If you have an interface you wish to use which you implement in the Groovy script you can use it as follows:"